# azure aztk installation pycryptodome

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pycryptodome

When I am installing the requirements for [Spark Aztk][1] there is an error while installing the dependencies for pycryptodome.

```
gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-z,relro build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src/MD2.o -L/usr/lib64 -lpython3.6m -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/Crypto/Hash/_MD2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3.6m
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I think the problem is that it might be an error in the installation script that is missing one space in the "python3.6m" file using "-lpython3.6m" instead. But I'm not sure. I don't know if it is possible to use a different version of the dependency or not. Because I have already installed python 3.6 properly.

The OS is CentOS on Azure.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem and saw that I didn't compiled the python interpreter correctly (I used --prefix but moved the interpreter to another place)